# JavaScript Get a part of strings with a specific pattern

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, replace

I want to extract a part of a variable with `` pattern. (start & end with)

```
let obj = {
   'THIS_IS_SOME_KEY_1': 'WORD_WORD_`VAR1`_WORD_`VAAR1`_WORD',
   'THIS_IS_SOME_KEY_2': '`VAR2`_WORD_WORD_VAAR2_WORD',
};
```

so i need this: 
    ['VAR1', 'VAAR1']

or 
    ['VAR2']

and also i need to change them later. 

any idea?

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: @HassanImam I'm actually looking for a way.

Comment: There are alot of examples out there about how to use regex for something like this. I have found this website really helpful too. https://regex101.com/

Comment: @arodjabel Thanks for sharing. Is there any way to extract these into array format? Or can they be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Regex` with `array#reduce`

```js
let obj = {
   'THIS_IS_SOME_KEY_1': 'WORD_WORD_`VAR1`_WORD_`VAAR1`_WORD',
   'THIS_IS_SOME_KEY_2': '`VAR2`_WORD_WORD_VAAR2_WORD',
};

var result = Object.values(obj).reduce(function(arr, line){
  return arr.concat(line.match(/`(.*?)`/g).map(word => word.replace(/`/g,'')));
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: note that `\w` only captures "word characters" or to be put more simply, is shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: I couldn't say nothing. Thank you Hassan, You made my day easy.